# draggable containment and resize window

Tags: jquery, resize, window, draggable

I have this code

```
   $(window).resize(function()
        {       
            x2 = $('#mask').offset().left;

        });

    $(image).draggable({cursor: 'move', containment: [ 0, 0, x2, 0]});
```

But I do not know how to implement drag and drop images to reflect the size of the browser window.

All I was trying to do, it did not work correctly or do not work. I am tired. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

All your `resize` code does is update the variable `x2`. The `Draggable` doesn't access that *variable*, it has a copy of the value that you passed it.

You can update the `Draggable`'s containment rectangle:

```
// Presumably you declare and initialize `x2` somewhere
// ...

// Create the Draggable with the initial bounds
$(image).draggable({cursor: 'move', containment: [ 0, 0, x2, 0]}); 

// Watch for resize
$(window).resize(function() {       
    // Recalc
    x2 = $('#mask').offset().left;

    // Update the existing draggable with its new bounds
    $(image).draggable("option", "containment", [ 0, 0, x2, 0]);
});
```

Separately, though, I'd look at this line in the `resize` handler:

```
x2 = $('#mask').offset().left;
```

Most of the time, the left coordinate of an element won't be affected by window resize. It *can* be, if the element is inline or something and so it's affected by word-wrap, or if it's moved around by floats, or its position is defined by a percentage, or a few other things, but *most* of the time, `left` is the only coordinate that tends not to change.

Also note that if you create the `Draggable` as a child element within an element that defines the boundaries of where you want to be able to drag it, you can get rid of the `resize` handler entirely and just use the option [`containment: "parent"`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment).

Comment: After resizing the window, recalculation is true.
But containment takes the wrong value. Why?

Comment: @john: Do you mean with your original code, or my example above? I think I explained why your original code wasn't working. The draggable doesn't have access to the `x2` variable and so doesn't see any changes you make to it; you have to update the containment option explicitly.

Comment: Your code! After resizing alert shows the correct recalculation but containment  takes a different value. Or it just will not accept new

Comment: @john: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/uhajiz/edit Note that you're constraining the image so it can't move vertically *at all* (by making by `y1` and `y2` both `0`), and you're constraining the left edge of it (not the right edge). If for some reason you *can't* use `containment: "parent"`, I'd probably centralize the calculation in a function and constraing its *right* edge by allowing for the image's width: http://jsbin.com/uhajiz/2/edit

Comment: T.J. Crowder, i'm sorry. This is my wrong. I just got confused in the code. Thank you very much for your help!!!:)